# custom MultiAutoCompleteTextView with drop down

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a class:

```
public class MultiObjectSelectorView extends LinearLayout {
    private List<String> items;
    private List<String> default_items;
    private List<String> display_items;
    private EditText text_feild;
    private ListView drop_down;

    public MultiObjectSelectorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.multiobjectselectorlayout, this, true);
        drop_down = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drop_down);
        text_feild = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MyTextView);
        display_items = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        final ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(context,display_items);
        drop_down.setAdapter(adapter);


        text_feild.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
                if(!s.toString().equals("")){
                    display_items = new ArrayList<String>(); 
                    String str = s.toString();
                    for(int i = 0;i<items.size();i++){
                        String[] splited = items.get(i).split("\\s+");
                        int isFound = 0;
                        for(int x = 0;x<splited.length;x++){
                            if(splited[x].startsWith(str)){
                                isFound = 1;
                                x = splited.length;
                            }
                        }
                        if(isFound == 1){
                            display_items.add(items.get(i));
                        }

                    }
                }else{
                    display_items = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                adapter.setListData(display_items);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {                   
            }       
        });
        drop_down.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
            }
        });
    }



    public void SetList(String[] list){
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0;i<list.length;i++){
            items.add(list[i]);
        }
        default_items = items;
    }

    public void SetList(String[] list,String[] list2){
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        default_items = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0;i<list.length;i++){
            items.add(list[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<list2.length;i++){
            default_items.add(list2[i]);
        }
    }
    public void SetList(String[] list,String[] list2,String[] list3){
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        default_items = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0;i<list.length;i++){
            items.add(list[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<list2.length;i++){
            default_items.add(list2[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<list3.length;i++){
            items.add(list3[i]);
        }
    }


    private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private List<String> values;

        public ListAdapter(Context context, List<String> values) {
            super(context, R.layout.dropdownlayout, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        public void setListData(List<String> values2){
            values = values2;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dropdownlayout, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.drop_down_text_view);
            textView.setText(values.get(position));
            return rowView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return values.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return values.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I don't use a MultiAutoCompleteTextView is that (1). I wanted the items in a drop down, (2). the drop downs not going to be used as an auto complete list it gives custom suggestions in a drop down view(they don't do anything yet, but eventually they'll add what is clicked on into a list).
The problem is that the listview, when expanded pushes down everything below the custom viewgroup. I would like it to overlay everything else.

also the layout file:

```
sion="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/MyTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/deit_restr_text"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drop_down"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```